# iOS CoreLocation API for beacons returns rssi 0

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, beacon

I spent 2 days cracking my head over why the `CLBeacon` is always returning the `RSSI` as `0` whether the beacon is `Far`, `Near` or `Immediate`. It doesn't matter it always return `RSSI` as `0`.

Tried changing the `TxPower` and `Advertising Interval`. Still no effect. The worst part is the `iOS` blocks the `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` before sending the advertisement data through `Core Bluetooth APIs`.

Please let me know what else can I do to receive a proper `RSSI`. I am running the app on `iOS 11.2.6` and `iPhone 7`.

For code reference, its Apple's own code. I am still getting `RSSI` as `0`. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Post your code. I haven't worked with iBeacons in quite a while, but I found they returned appropriate RSSI values.

Comment: A RSSI of 0 is returned when no beacon packets have been received in a one second ranging cycle.  Apple continues to return ranging callbacks for about 5 seconds after the beacon disappears.  The 0 value indicates it was not seen in this ranging cycle but may still be around.  Could this explain what you see?  Do you *ever* see a nonzero value?

Comment: No, I am not seeing a non-zero value at all. I always get a 0, so it is kind of confusing on whats going wrong.

Comment: @davidgyoung,
Can you post a link to Apple's documentation that describes that 0 indicates that beacon was not seen? I see few people mentioning this behavior online and would like to understand details better.

Comment: @Alex, to my knowledge there is no such documentation -- lots of Apple API details are undocumented! But it is easy to confirm this for yourself -- just open a beacon scanner app that shows the RSSI.  Turn on a beacon and watch the RSSI fluctuate.  Then turn of your beacon and notice that the RSSI goes to 0 for a few seconds before it drops off the screen.

Comment: Thank you, @davidgyoung. I really appreciate this clarification!